# Kafka Stream: Kafka Windowed Stream behavior on application restart

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Working on a simple stream of data (say inputStream), for example:
Notice that value is updated for the same key and timestamp.

```
|-----|--------|-------|
| Key | TS(ms) | Value |
|-----|--------|-------|
|  A  | 1000   |   0   |
|  B  | 1000   |   0   |
|  A  | 61000  |   0   |
|  B  | 61000  |   0   |
|  A  | 121000 |   0   |
|  B  | 121000 |   0   |
|  A  | 1000   |   1   |
|  B  | 1000   |   1   |
|  A  | 61000  |   1   |
|  B  | 61000  |   1   |
|  A  | 121000 |   1   |
|  B  | 121000 |   1   |
```

Here is the code:

```
 KStream<Windowed<String>, Long> aggregatedStream = inputStream
            .groupByKey()
            .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(1)).grace(Duration.ofMinutes(1)))
            .count(Materialized.as("count-metric"))
            .toStream();

    aggregatedStream.print(Printed.toSysOut());
```

The output of print is

```
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000014]: [A@0/60000], 1
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000014]: [B@0/60000], 1
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000014]: [A@60000/120000], 1
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000014]: [B@60000/120000], 1
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000014]: [A@120000/180000], 1
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000014]: [B@120000/180000], 1
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000014]: [A@60000/120000], 2
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000014]: [B@60000/120000], 2
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000014]: [A@120000/180000], 2
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000014]: [B@120000/180000], 2
```

Since the GracePeriod is set to 1min, the count for windows [A@0/60000] and [B@0/60000] is not incremented when the value is updated to 1 in the input stream for the same key and time stamp. The output is shown as expected.

But when i restart my streams application and ingest the same input stream again, iam seeing the following output:

```
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000014]: [A@0/60000], 2
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000014]: [B@0/60000], 2
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000014]: [A@60000/120000], 2
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000014]: [B@60000/120000], 2
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000014]: [A@120000/180000], 2
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000014]: [B@120000/180000], 2
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000014]: [A@60000/120000], 3
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000014]: [B@60000/120000], 3
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000014]: [A@120000/180000], 3
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000014]: [B@120000/180000], 3
```

Why does the window [A@0/60000] and [B@0/60000] gets updated to 2 after restarting the application?
Before restarting the application the streamTime is 121000 and the window [A@0/60000] and [B@0/60000] already exceeded the grace period and closed.
Why is this window considered after restart again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9368

During a rebalance, the `aggregation()` operator "forgets" the current time and when restarted it only "re-learns" the time base on the new records it sees. This affect how grace period is applied.